# submit form and keeping values setting

Tags: forms, jsp, jstl

I want to know if there is a way to submit a form but at the same time keep the values selected and edited(without reset).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague... You will likely need to use PHP (cookies) to store the entries / changes.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Comment: So to be clear I use JSTL to be able to change the second table in my form according to values from 3 ddl.So using the JSTL should be with a submit button at the same time I don't want to loose values from the 3 ddl I want to display it at the same time.
I am using JSP/servlet with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net MVC, you may set the page with the form to submit to inherit an instance of a class which properties are set automatically.

In order to keep the values after the submit, you just have to place the object model as the same object that you received as an argument in the action, like this return View("ViewName", object).

But anyway, your question could have been a little more specific. Hope that if you are using .Net, this may be useful.

Comment: As per the comments (and question history) the OP is using JSP.